# ROR Many to many association ,index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails and i'm building this application which have 3 models Customer, Ad, CustomerAd 
where seen is params customer_ad
I want CustomerAd to display all Ad and Customer watch them
    So when Customer click on one of Ads list (show ad) 
    CustomerAd will update seen to true
    I'm using:

```
Customer
  has_many :customer_ads
  has_many :ads through: :customer_ads

Ad
  has_many :customer_ads
  has_many :customers through: :customer_ads

CustomerAd
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :ad
```

## views/ads/show

```
%body    
        %div{:align => "auto", :dir => "auto"}
          %p#notice= notice
          %p
            %strong= t('activerecord.attributes.ad.business_id')
            = @ad.business_id
          %p
            %strong= t('activerecord.attributes.ad.short_description')
            = @ad.short_description
          %p
            %strong= t('activerecord.attributes.ad.long_description')
            = @ad.long_description
          %p
            %strong= t('activerecord.attributes.ad.start_date')
            = @ad.start_date
          %p
            %strong= t('activerecord.attributes.ad.end_date')
            = @ad.end_date  
          = link_to t('views.ad.show.edit'), edit_ad_path(@ad)
          |
          \#{link_to t('views.ad.show.back'), customer_ads_path}
```

## View customer_ad index and controllers

```
              %tbody                  
                - @ads.each do |ad| 
                  - if @customer_ad.seen == true
                    %tr#btn.seen{"data-link" => "#{ad_path(ad)}"}
                      %td
                        = ad.short_description
                        = ad.long_description

                  - else
                    %tr#btn.unseen{"data-link" => "#{ad_path(ad)}"}
                      %td
                        = ad.short_description
                        = ad.long_description
```

CustomerAdsController

```
class CustomerAdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer_ad, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]    
  def index        
    @ads = Ad.all
  end

  private
    def set_customer_ad
      @customer_ad = CustomerAd.find(params[:id])
    end


    def customer_ad_params
      params.require(:customer_ad).permit(:customer_id, :ad_id, :bought, :seen)
    end
end
```

AdsController

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ad, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] 

  def show
   ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
   current_customer.customer_ads.where(ad_id: ad.id).update(seen: true)
  end 

 def new
  @ad = Ad.new
 end

def edit
end

def create
  @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)    

  respond_to do |format|
    if @ad.save
      format.html { redirect_to customer_ads_url }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ad }
    else 
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @ad.update(ad_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ad }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @ad.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to ads_url, notice: 'Ad was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  def set_ad
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end

  def ad_params
    params.require(:ad).permit(:business_id, :short_description, :long_description, :start_date, :end_date, :filter_id, :maximum_number_of_customers_targeted, :tokens_allocated_for_reading, :tokens_allocated_for_purchasing)
  end
end
```

Comment: Use proper model names instead of A, Bs etc.
Use code highlight & format things so what one can understand what you asked.

Comment: I modified it @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you want. and what the exact issue is

Comment: you want to update customer_ad with seen true when user clicks on show?

Comment: the exact issue is that seen is not updating  show ad action !
@DeepakMahakale

Comment: yes @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: & customer logged in at that time?

Comment: Exactly @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: Customer is devise user @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def show
  ad = Ad.find params[:id]
  current_customer.cusomer_ads.where(ad_id: ad.id).update(seen: true)
end
```

You will update customer_ad against current_customer & that specific ad.
in current_customer, you will have logged in customer.

On Index Page, you will do something  like

```
- @ads.each do |ad|
    - @customer_ad = ad.customer_ads.where(customer_id: current_customer.id).first
    - if @customer_ad.present? && @customer_ad.seen == true
      %tr#btn.seen{"data-link" => "#{ad_path(ad)}"}
        %td
          = ad.short_description
          = ad.long_description

    - else
      %tr#btn.unseen{"data-link" => "#{ad_path(ad)}"}
        %td
          = ad.short_description
          = ad.long_description
```

From Code What I think is that you are placing code to update **seen** to true in AdsController but giving user link to show page for CustomerAdsControoler's show page

place following code in CustomerAdsController

```
def show
 ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
 current_customer.customer_ads.where(ad_id: ad.id).update(seen: true)
end
```

**Make row clickable**

```
  $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).data("link")
    })
```

Comment: yes thanks, but check the below code please  @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: @BYBY look at edited answer,
There are things like eager loading to avoid this query in view but first see that it worked for you

Comment: This code worked but still just got index page with list of ads ,
update seen to true is not working at show !
I also edit my question @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: on click at show can you check in database that related customer_ad updated with seen true ?

Comment: & have you used exactly what I told for index page?

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and in database
customer_ad params are nill :(
I'll share CustomerAds controller to be more clear

Comment: CustomerAdsController???
You should have AdsController with index, create, show etc.

Comment: I have Ads controller with full actions but i want CustomerAds just to be index page for ads that user should see @MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: you should have handle all that AdsController, 
update your question with code of both controllers.

Comment: changed customer_ad = ad.customer_ad.where(customer_id: current_customer.id).first to - customer_ad = ad.customer_ads.where(customer_id: current_customer.id).first (hopefully you have already changed it).
& show the code in view where user clicks to show add ?

Comment: I asked for that index page where you give user a link to show page

Comment: Look at views/customer_ads/index please.. table's  row linked to show ad page..
@MuhammadFaisalIqbal

Comment: are you using js too for this click thing?

Comment: if not than add it as I edited in answer, otherwise install byebug gem & place in show method & see what happens there.

Comment: I'm using all those codes @MuhammadFaisalIqbal 
Still not change seen in view :(

Comment: It's work finally , i changed it a little bit.. thanks alot  @MuhammadFaisalIqbal